# Slack API Python Client Cannot search for channels

Tags: python, python-3.x, slack, slack-api

I am trying to search my Slack workspace for channels with matching name using Python library.

The end goal is to set the purpose of channels using the tool. That API requires channel_id as parameter.

My observation is that the search function works for some channel names but fails for others. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
from utils import *
import slack

def slack_get_client():
    fdata = get_settings()
    client = slack.WebClient(token=fdata["slack"]["token"])
    return client

def slack_search_channel(query=""):
    client = slack_get_client()

    r = client.search_all(query=query)
    if r["ok"]:
        matches = r["messages"]["matches"]
        for m in matches:
            if m["channel"]["is_channel"] and query == m["channel"]["name"]:
                channel_id = m["channel"]["id"]
                return True, channel_id
    return False, ""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    r,c = slack_search_channel( "abc-test") # this exists
    if r:
        print( "channel found", c)  # this is printed
    else:
        print( "channel not found")

    r,c = slack_search_channel( "abc-debug20191009") # this also exists
    if r:
        print( "channel found", c)
    else:
        print( "channel not found")  # this is printed
```

Notes:
* To clarify: this script is running as admin user. I have checked by manually logging in that it has access to all channels.
* The only difference I can see in the channel name is their length. Updated the code above with real names.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of the channel names you have success with, and ones that you don't. Also are there any differences in channel permissions?

Comment: Does it maybe not work for some private channels? if so the reason is that the user who installed your app has no access to those channels.

Comment: Did you get to work? If not please answer the questions, so we can help you find a solution.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response. 
* The missing channels are not private channels
* These were created by same user and that user is a member of that channel.
* I logged in (interactive mode web UI) to confirm if that channel appears in search results: yes it does.
* I double checked that I am not missing any search results, I am not.
* Only difference I could find was the length of channel name, that's it.
Therefore: this problem remains unresolved. 
I searched elsewhere, did not find any examples of how this could be done better, I did not find any examples.